# Scrapy - extract href from link with specific attribute value

Tags: html, css, scrapy, href

I'm working with Scrapy. I have a list of `a-carousel-card` where I'm tring to extract the href from the second element. The following code only extracts the first link it finds. The only difference between these cards is a `aria-posinset` attribute with the values `"1"`, `"2"`, etc.

```
response.css("li.a-carousel-card a::attr(href)").extract_first()
```

I'm very unsure about how I extract the href from the second element in the list.
Something like `response.css("li.a-carousel-card a[aria-posinset="2"] a::attr(href)").extract_first()`, but this gives me a syntax error at "2".

The first element is

`<li class="a-carousel-card a-float-left" role="listitem" aria-setsize="100" aria-posinset="1" aria-hidden="false" style="margin-left: 14px;">`,

while the other is

`<li class="a-carousel-card a-float-left" role="listitem" aria-setsize="100" aria-posinset="2" aria-hidden="false" style="margin-left: 14px;">`

The only difference between the two are the value in `aria-posinset`: "1" and "2".

How would I accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You either need to escape the double quotes inside string or you need to use single quotes. You need to use below

```
response.css("li.a-carousel-card[aria-posinset='2'] a::attr(href)").extract_first()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've edited my question, as I'm getting `None`. Are you able to look at it again, please?

Comment: The attribute is on li and not a, so you should check it on li. please see updated answer